# How to get data from AOT of MS Dynamic AX by Excel

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I can get data by function of MS Excel on table of database of Microsoft SQL Server 
[image]

### However I do not know how to get data from AOT of Dynamic Ax 2012-R3 the same by Excel

Here is the AOT of MS Dynamic Ax
[image]

It's really hard to us.I'm looking for hearing from you soon

Comment: Please take a look at the following link https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/tinkerersnotebook/posts/using-the-dynamics-ax-excel-add-in

Answer (score 1):

You can export many forms, lists, and reports from Microsoft Dynamics AX and Enterprise Portal for Microsoft Dynamics AX to Microsoft Excel. If a form, list, or report has an Export to Microsoft Excel button on the Action Pane, you can export the data to Excel.

If your system administrator has installed the Office Add-ins for Microsoft Dynamics AX, a Dynamics AX tab is added to the ribbon in Excel. If your user role has access to data in the Microsoft Dynamics AX client and the permissions to refresh exported data, you can refresh the data that you export from Microsoft Dynamics AX into Excel.

[image]

Please see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/using-the-microsoft-dynamics-ax-add-in-for-excel)